# how to override new push notification with new push notification in notification panel

Tags: android, push-notification

I am working with push notification and **i want that whenever new push notification comes it overrides old push notification** ,in my case this is going good when my app is in foreground but when i put **my app in background it is creating new notification in notification panel.**

> **MyFirebaseMessagingService.class**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,TabActivityClass.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    {
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_logo)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    } else
    {
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_logo)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    }
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

> Screenshot
>   [image]

I want to show only latest notification in notification panel
Thank you in advance

Comment: Just use the same notification id. it'll replace the old notification with the new one.

Comment: @SamuelRobert I am using same notification id always but it is creating new notification ,i dont want this

Comment: Did you checkout my answer below?

Comment: @SamuelRobert Yes i have tried it check my code also i have used same notification id ,but is also doing same that i dont want

Comment: post your notification send request code from server

Comment: @SamuelRobert https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4heJhgwlwgoNlhQbWstOTFIUlE/view?usp=sharing ,complete class

Comment: That's not what I asked... Post the request parameters that you would request to FCM server from your server to deliver the message. I think your onMessageReceived() method is not executing, Android is using a system notification tray to generate notification instead of your MyFirebaseMessagingService.class when your app is in background.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154637/discussion-between-sunil-and-samuel-robert).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you configure notification from server. In that case system won't invoke the `onMessageReceived` method, rather uses a system tray to send out a notification.

> When your app is in the background, Android directs notification messages to the system tray. A user tap on the notification opens the app launcher by default.
>
> This includes messages that contain both notification and data payload (and all messages sent from the Notifications console). In these cases, the notification is delivered to the device's system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

In order to avoid this issue remove the notification json object from the request to FCM server and just keep the data payload. This will trigger the `onMessageReceived` method even if the app is in background. You can handle the notification there just like you are doing now.